# run jQuery codes on ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an variable which contain some HTML+CSS+JavaScript codes Like this:

```
<ul class="tabs">
   <li data-tab="tab1">Item 1</li>
   <li data-tab="tab2">Item 2</li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1"></div>
<div id="tab2"></div>
<script src="http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })
})
</script>
```

now I want run this code in my page so in template I wrote :

```
<ion-view>
    <ion-content >
        <div ng-bind-html="data"></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and in my controller I wrote:

```
$scope.data = $sce.trustAsHtml(that variable);
```

Ok, every thing is ok and all CSS and HTML will load, but javascript code cannot work, so I search in Google and found this code:
http://jsfiddle.net/NWZZE/6/

so I changed my code and add `directive` like this:

```
.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(
                function(scope) {
                    // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
                    return scope.$eval(attrs.compile);
                },
                function(value) {
                    // when the 'compile' expression changes
                    // assign it into the current DOM
                    element.html(value);

                    // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
                    // scope.
                    // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
                    // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }
            );
        };
    }])
```

and then use `compile` instead of `ng-bind-html` but my javascript code cannot work yet !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS uses jqLite, a small subset of jQuery. The problem in your case is that jqLite doesn't support script tags. The AngularJS team decided not to implement this since getting it to work on all supported browsers involves a lot of code.

jQuery however supports script tags. So to get it to work you will need to load jQuery before AngularJS, which will make AngularJS use jQuery instead of jqLite.

This means that the following line is of course redundant and can be removed:

```
<script src="http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js"></script>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Pjg0ZrGmDD8WfG4tqXxG?p=preview